# Using identifiers and values from other places in a Spring CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm learning how to `extend` Spring's `CrudRepository` interface to create a repository for an entity.  But I'm having trouble implementing more complicated queries that use values that aren't hard-coded.  Here's a contrived example.  The HQL is not valid, but it shows what I'm trying to do:

```
import mypackage.DogTypeEnum;
public interface myRepository extends CrudRepository<Dog, Integer> {
   int oldAge = 10;  // years - old for a dog

   @Query(SELECT dog From Dog dog WHERE dog.age > oldAge and dog.type = DogTypeEnum.poodle
   public List<Dog> findOldPoodles()
}
```

So in the above example, I'm trying to query for all dogs of type poodle that are over a certain age threshold.  I don't want to hard code either `poodle` or the value `10` because these values that will be used elsewhere in the code as well and I want to avoid duplication.  I don't want to require the user to pass those values in as parameters either.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what do you meant by you dont want to hardcode and don't want the user to pass the values as parameter? then how and where you will you expect these values to come from?

Comment: I meant, for example, that I want `... WHERE dog.age > oldAge...` instead of `...WHERE dog.age > 10...`, because `oldAge` is a variable declared elsewhere (in this case, it's declared in the interface, in the case of `DogTypeEnum` , it was imported) so that logic isn't duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'll never have this problem, if you structure your project as the next package architecture shows, you won't have this problem:

> View (Angular, JSP, JSF...)   -- APP
>
> Controller                    -- APP
>
> Services -- Main Core
>
> DAO -- Main Core
>
> Entities -- Main Core

This way you make more modular, escalable, maintainable and comprehensive application.

It doesn't matter what technology you use in your view, you just have to invoque the correct method on the service.

In here, on the services package you could have a service for example:

```
@Service
public class ServiceDog extends Serializable {
   @Autowired
   private MyRepository myRepository;

   int oldAge = 10;

   public List<Dog> findOldPoodles() throws ServicioException {
     return myRepository.findAllByAgeGreaterThanAndType(oldAge, DogTypeEnum.poodle);
   }
}
```

Now you could use all the advantage you get from using [spring-data-jpa reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) or make a more simple JPQL Query.

This is a simple example but this way you make sure that each DAO speak with only one entity (It will only have the methods needed for this entity like save, delete.. with no dependencies with other DAOs), and the service are the ones on calling the different DAOs and make the necessary actions on them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Interface that extend your repository as like this:

```
//Only complex querys
    public interface MyRepositoryCustom {
    List<Dog> findOldPoodles()
    }
```

// Your Repository must extends to MyRepositoryCustom

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Dog, Integer>, MyRepositoryCustom {
    // Declare query methods
}
```

//More complex query

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepositoryCustom {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public List<Dog> findOldPoodles() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT dog From Dog dog WHERE dog.age > :oldAge and dog.type = :type");
    query.setParameter("oldAge",10);
    query.setParameter("type",DogTypeEnum.poodle.name);

    return query.getResultList();
}
}
```

Remember all java class starts with a Upper Case letter.

This link can help you: [Spring repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)